# gzip file - does it have a block header like bzip2 does?

Tags: compression, gzip, file-format

Every compressed block in bzip2 format have a header, which begins with `".compressed_magic:48            = 0x314159265359 (BCD (pi))"`. So It can be rather easy to detect middle of big bzip2 in binary form.

Does the gzip format have the same magic constants in the middle of the big file?

or this question is like: does gzip have a gziprecover like bzip2 has bzip2recover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html I didnt reread it, but as far as I remember, then no block headers in that format.

Comment: there is no info about format of compressed data itself at this link

Comment: Gzip is just a container, so that belongs to the compression format used. Usually deflate: http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-deflate.html#block-format

Comment: Deflate has only 3-bit header (zero bit and two bits for coding method, one of 00/01/10) and varibale compressed block size. Header is not byte-aligned.